# Protected Route With Firebase and Svelte

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a protected page, the profile page of my project. I want to throw people out if they are not logged in. I'm trying to do it as simply as possible. I find this tutorial, but is TypeScript and I couldn't get it to work. [Link >](https://phptuts.github.io/svelte-docs/firebase-recipe-site/login/)

My way:
Profile page:

```js
let auth = getAuth();

    onMount(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                goto('/signin');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to have a user store and use it with the combination of `onAuthStateChanged`

```js
import authStore from '../stores/authStore';; // <~ stores.ts 
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

let auth = getAuth();

onMount(() => {
  //shift this method to a firebase.ts
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      authStore.set({
        user,
      });
    } else {
      authStore.set({
        user: null,
      });
    }
  });
});

// this block will watch changes on the store
$: {
  if (!$authStore.user) {
    if (browser) goto('/login');
  } else {
    if (browser) goto('/');
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no 'currentUser' in authStore.ts https://github.com/phptuts/firebase-sveltekit-recipe-site/blob/master/src/stores/authStore.ts sorry, I'm lost in this one.

Comment: in that case, just replace the `currentUser` with `authStore`, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems that I have an issue with firebase. ```user?: firebase.UserInfo```.  Error:  ```has no exported member 'UserInfo'```.  Iwill try to solve it myself.